Relationship problem: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table
I'm trying to implement partitioning in PostgreSQL. The problem is that one partitioned table references another partitioned table. There is also a third regular table that also references the partitioned table. The problem is precisely in the reference to the partitioned table.
Every attempt I make to create an FK results in an error like this:
there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "units"

This error occurs due to migration of the lessons table.
The table columns have simple and clear names: id, unit_id, etc.:
t.belongs_to :unit, type: :uuid, null: false, foreign_key: true

I can use this code to create a column:
t.belongs_to :unit, type: :uuid, null: false

But as a result, foreign keys will not be created.
Can you please tell me in detail what needs to be done?
UPD
Examples of migration:
create_range_partition :units, id: :uuid, partition_key: :created_at, template: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :course, type: :uuid, null: false, foreign_key: true

  # ...

  t.timestamps
end

create_range_partition :lessons, id: :uuid, partition_key: :created_at, template: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :unit, type: :uuid, null: false, foreign_key: true # <= THIS WILL CAUSE AN ERROR

  # t.belongs_to :unit, type: :uuid, null: false # <= THIS WILL BE CREATED

  # ...

  t.timestamps
end


Please share the DDL for the tables involved. We can now only guess. And why do you need partitioning?

Pretty straightforward the parent(referenced) table does not have a UNIQUE constraint on the field that the child(referencing) table is attaching a FK to.

@AdrianKlaver I tried this. It asks to create a unique index for all columns involved in the partitioning. For units these are the id and created_at columns. Creating this index still results in the error remaining. Example: ALTER TABLE units ADD CONSTRAINT unit_unique_id_created_at UNIQUE (id, created_at);


Per @FrankHeikens comment use psql to get the actual table definitions and add as text update to question text. 2) The UNIQUE constraint is on the combination of id and created_at whereas it looks to me like the FK is on only one field.


@FrankHeikens I've added some example code from migrations

@AdrianKlaver I don't quite understand. If uniqueness needs to be created only for the id column, then I can't do it. Error: unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns

I have no idea what kind of DDL is created by Ruby on rails, you have to share it. Check your (database) log files. And what problem should table partitioning solve? Aka, do you need it at all?

Bottom line the child FK needs to reference the column or columns that constitute a UNIQUE constraint on the parent table. If the child table does not have those columns then you can't create a FK. In other words child_table.id <---> parent_table.id will not work if id is only part of the UNIQUE constraint on parent_table.

Avoid using partitioned tables unless there is a compelling, and demonstrable, benefit to be gained by their use (e.g., large volumes of time partitioned data that needs to be purged regularly). Working with partitioned tables introduces complexity and limitations.
The first bulleted item in PostgreSQL 17, Section 5.12.2.3. Limitations states (emphasis mine):

To create a unique or primary key constraint on a partitioned table, the partition keys must not include any expressions or function calls and the constraint's columns must include all of the partition key columns. This limitation exists because the individual indexes making up the constraint can only directly enforce uniqueness within their own partitions; therefore, the partition structure itself must guarantee that there are not duplicates in different partitions.

The requirement to include the partition key as part of a partitioned table's unique index, means that foreign key constraints referencing a partitioned table must also include references to those columns. In the OP's specific case, the foreign key constraint from lessons to units would have to reference units(id, created_at).
The following is example code for setting up migrations and classes to use PostgreSQL partitioned tables in a Ruby on Rails application (this code depends on the pg_party gem).
# db/migrate/20241103010658_create_courses.rb
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :courses, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# app/models/course.rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :units
end

# db/migrate/20241103010710_create_units.rb
class CreateUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def up
    create_range_partition :units, id: :uuid, partition_key: :created_at, template: false do |t|
      t.uuid :course_id, null: false
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :units, [:id, :created_at], unique: true
    execute "ALTER TABLE units ADD FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses(id)"
    create_range_partition_of :units, name: :units_2024, start_range: "2024-01-01", end_range: "2025-01-01"
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP TABLE units"
  end
end

# app/models/unit.rb
class Unit < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = [:id, :created_at]
  has_many :lessons
end

# db/migrate/20241103010717_create_lessons.rb
class CreateLessons < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def up
    create_range_partition :lessons, id: :uuid, partition_key: :created_at, template: false do |t|
      t.uuid :unit_id
      t.timestamp :unit_created_at
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :lessons, [:id, :created_at], unique: true
    execute "ALTER TABLE lessons ADD FOREIGN KEY (unit_id, unit_created_at) REFERENCES units(id, created_at)"
    create_range_partition_of :lessons, name: :lessons_2024, start_range: "2024-01-01", end_range: "2025-01-01"
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP TABLE lessons"
  end
end

# app/models/lesson.rb
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = [:id, :created_at]
  belongs_to :unit, query_constraints: [:unit_id, :unit_created_at]
end

ActiveRecord's support of composite foreign keys and partitioned tables is limited. One of the artifacts associated with ActiveRecord's handling of composite primary keys is demonstrated below where u is an instance of type Unit as defined above:
irb(main):005> u
=>
#<Unit:0x0000000127166098
 id: "864f835d-ff27-4cf5-bdd7-fdc6e065a529",
 course_id: "451c8e20-e119-4a5b-a22b-97ffaf2a3e1a",
 title: "First Unit",
 created_at: Sun, 03 Nov 2024 07:01:14.202998000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 03 Nov 2024 07:01:14.202998000 UTC +00:00>
irb(main):006> u.id
=> ["864f835d-ff27-4cf5-bdd7-fdc6e065a529", Sun, 03 Nov 2024 07:01:14.202998000 UTC +00:00]
irb(main):007> u["id"]
=> "864f835d-ff27-4cf5-bdd7-fdc6e065a529"
irb(main):008> u[:id]
=> "864f835d-ff27-4cf5-bdd7-fdc6e065a529"

Note that u["id"] and u[:id] return the same value, but u.id returns an array representing the composite primary key. This could easily lead to subtle defects in code.
